# Can I replace or repair the rubber wrapper for ease of holding my Rebel T2i?

Tags: body, repair

I just got my Rebel T2i in the last two or three months, and since I haven't bought a camera bag yet, I just take my camera in my backpack with my notebook and other accessories.

I don't know how long it has been, but just yesterday when I was cleaning my lens & body, I noticed that rubber (the exact place is shown on the photo below) is torn a little bit from the top-middle area.

[image: rebelt2i ~ RubberWrapped Area !]

I know... it isn't important, but I don't think it really feels nice when I'm holding camera with that torn part there.  I'm wondering if there is anyway to fix it at home, or can I replace it? Does Canon or a third party release spare-parts?

Also, what do photographers call that? I really don't know the name of that part, so I'm not even sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: That would be the "grip" of the camera, or more specifically the shutter hand grip, as more expensive professional cameras also have a vertical (sometimes called the "battery") grip as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can get replacement grips from parts suppliers for $20-$30 or so, or you can get it fixed (mostly that will mean replaced) by a repair center. If the camera is as new as yours, that would likely fall under warranty, your dealer should be able to confirm that. If not, when done in combination with regular servicing/cleaning (which you don't need yet, given the age of the camera) they'll usually do it for the cost of the parts alone (which won't cost much more than getting them from a 3rd party), else it'll cost total maybe $50 (and you'll be without the camera for up to a week or so when fixing it yourself takes all of 5 minutes).
Don't try to fix it with glue, the rubber grip needs to be able to come off to get at the screws underneath for repairs (the rubber is attached to the body using strong doublesided adhesive tape) :)

Answer (score 2):

If it is the grip coming loose, you can get it repair but its unlikely it will be free.

It would help to have a photograph of your camera shown so we can see just how badly it is "torn".

If it looks like it wasn't made properly in the first place (poorly glued-on for example) and it is still within warranty period, you should be able to get it fixed.

I am not sure if your grip rubber has a small piece torn off of it, or its just normal wear that makes the surface very rough. So I can't say without seeing if its a good idea to get it repair or not.

Bottom line is, camera is a tool. A tool is only useful when used. With use comes wear. I think a worn camera is much better than a camera kept in a glass shelf.